# How to establish output connection to Oracle server by Log Parser query?

Tags: oracle, cmd, odbc, connection-string, logparser

I am trying to execute a Log parser query through command prompt whose output is supposed to be stored into an Oracle table.

I have tried and achieved to do so when using SQL Server, with the following code:

```
logparser -i:TEXTLINE  "Select  LogFilename as LogFile, substr(text, 0, 23) as col1 INTO LOG_ERROR_TABLE  from C:\temp\ErrorLog*" -o:sql -server:localhost -database:MyDB1 -username:Max -password:password
```

But When trying to execute the below query in Oracle server , I am getting :

```
logparser -i:TEXTLINE  "Select  LogFilename as LogFile, substr(text, 0, 23) as col1 INTO LOG_ERROR_TABLE  from C:\temp\ErrorLog*" -o:SQL -oConnString:"Driver={Oracle in OraDB18Home1};Server=OracleServerName;Uid=Max;Pwd=password;"
```

[image: Image of Error on running the above command for Oracle]

I saw plenty of other ODBC drivers installed in the server but I am not sure which one to use(if that's where I am going wrong)
The version of Oracle installed is: 18.0.0.0.0 on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Many sites block links, and many people here will not follow a link for the same reason others block it.  You need to show it in your message.  If you have an error message, start by googling it.

Comment: The best way forward would be to create a DSN (via `odbcad32.exe`) and reference that in the LogParser command-line query.